# how do I place html tag inside div in ngTemplateOutlet?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a component that uses ngTemplateOutlet , i need to place tag from the user of this component inside a div of this component.

this is the DynamicTableVersatileTemplate:

```
<div class="table-container">

    <ng-container 
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="versatileTableTemplateRef" 
      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: this.dataTable}">

    <div class = "toolbar">
        
            <mat-form-field  appearance="outline" fxFlex="100"  class="pr-4" width="100%"
            class="my-form-field">
            <mat-label>Search </mat-label>
                <input type="text"  matInput [(ngModel)]="detailTableFilter"  autocomplete="off">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

I need to place an add icon inside the div with the class **toolbar** from the parent component.

- the mat-form-field tag must come from the child component and the add event must come from the parent component.
- both tags need to be under the same div with css class **toolbar**

this is the code of the parent component:

```
<tk-dynamic-table-versatile [metadata]="this.children[0].metadata" [recordPosition]="this.processedEntryForm.data.position" [title]="title"
            [isViewMode]="this.processedEntryForm.data.isViewMode" [detailEntityName]="children[0].id" [tableSource]="this.tableSource"
            [eventCode]="this.processedEntryForm.eventCode" [dataFromRow]="this.processedEntryForm.data" [parentData]="this.processedEntryForm.data.masterEntityData"
            [isNotEditable]="false" [entityDsc]="children[0].dsc" #dynamictable1>
        
            <ng-template #versatileTableTemplate let-dynamictable>

                
                <div class="toolbar">
                    <div class="icon-container">
                        <ng-container *ngIf="!isViewMode && !isNotEditable">
                            <button style="background-color: #5cb85c;" mat-mini-fab matTooltip="Add"  class = "header-button" (click)="this.getFormControl('currCode').value && this.getFormControl('currCode').value != '' ?  dynamictable1.eventPressed ( dynamictable1.emptyFieldIdsForAdd,null,'ADD' , true, false , false ) : triggerWarningMessage() " mat-button>
                                <mat-icon 
                               >add</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                        </ng-container>
                    </div>
                </div>
              
                <table class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover my-table">
                ...etc
                 </table>
```

as you can see there are two divs with the css class **toolbar** one in the parent and one in the child , any ideas on how to unite the elements inside one div of this class?

to summarize:

```
<div class = "toolbar"> ... </div>
```

this div appears in both components **dynamicTableVersatile** and the parent component.

i need to have 1 of this div that contain the elements from the parent and the child.

Comment: Can you explain more, I can not get your problem ?

Comment: i edited the question, hope it's not confusing now

Comment: `how to unite the elements inside one div of this class?` this part is not clear to me